# How to check whether it is from remote branch or local branch in post checkout hooks?

Tags: git

How do I check whether the checkout branch is from remote or local in the post-checkout hooks ?

Answer (score 1):

That's somehow invalid question. You can checkout only local branch. If you checkout origin/branch you'll end up in state of detached head.

FYI local post-checkout hook will receive

- Ref of previous HEAD
- Ref of new HEAD
- Whether this is a file checkout - 0; or branch checkout - 1

Comment: I dont think so... If you checking out new branch, initially it checks for local index, if not found it will get the branch from remote origin..

Comment: but that would become local copy of a branch and then it would perform checkout. If you think that it was asked in your sense than question can be simplified - is there local copy of a branch before checkout. I'll append this in edit.